# How to click a reCAPTCHA checkbox in a robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, checkbox, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

[demoqa registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThCgj.jpg) it's my first time writing here and I am having a hard time finding a way to select a checkbox in a robot framework. The site is demoqa.com/register. I can't test the registration, because I can't find a way to select the checkbox. I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Please add details on which checkbox you are trying to select.

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: Assuming you are part of the team that wrote that page (otherwise, why are you testing it?), have you asked the dev team for a way to avoid having to click the box during an automated test? Clearly, the reCaptcha is specifically designed to prevent automation of the web page.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I have been studying Selenium for the last two months.. I am not part of a team i.e I am yet to become a software tester. This demoqa.com is just a site that has been given to us to exercise automation testing on. That is all. We have tested checkboxes, but not reCaptcha, hence, I am here :) I understand that the checkbox is specifically made for it not to be automated.. That is what it is suppose to do... If there's no other possible way, except for your advice here(to avoid), then I will add in my project that it is impossible to automate it and leave it at that.

Comment: There are certain things which can't be automated and which should not be automated. For instance, captcha, billing, graphs and etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple checkbox, it's reCAPTCHA to prevent bots creating fake accounts. You can't click it with RobotFramework.

Comment: does it mean there is no way I can test it? :(

Comment: @Gordana88   There are ways but not full proof. and they may cost you. And eventually you will end up at from where you started.

Comment: You can test but it's vice versa. You can test if captcha preventing bots from creating accounts. If you can't create an account with automated test then it means captcha is working and your test is valid but it depends on requirements.

Comment: @Bobur Meliev yes, i understand... thank you for your answers